# Display Campaign in Opportunity/Donation List Views

Tags: list-view, custom-view

I am trying to modify a "view" for donations, so that I can see the Primary Campaign Source. When I clicked "Edit" to edit the view, I don't see campaign in the list of fields.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the field called something slightly different like just "Source"?  If you go in to edit a view, all the currently displayed fields will be in the **right-side Box** for choosing fields to display (and order)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the `Campaign` field is not available for display in Opportunity (Donation) views.  There's a [feature request](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bq5wAAC) on the Salesforce IdeaExchange to make this field available, so I recommend voting for that.

As a work-around in the meantime, you could create a custom formula field called `Campaign Name`, and display that instead.